# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 via USB stick

Tags: boot, grub2

To install Ubuntu 22.04 on my old notebook (HB Pavilion dv6), I created a bootable USB stick (with Ubuntu 22.04) according to the instructions here.
When restarting the notebook with the USB stick inserted, the display only shows "GRUB" at the top left.
Nothing else, there is no installation.
I've tried several times, but always the same thing:
Display GRUB and nothing more.
Please maybe someone can give me a tip what I could do there.
Many thanks in advance!

Servus from Austria!

Comment: What exactly were "the instructions here" you followed?

Comment: Did you remember to [verify the ISO you downloaded](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) to ensure you had the complete image beforehand?

Comment: The instructions from here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#2-requirements